# How do I access a Docker Containers Contents

Tags: linux, docker, containers, system-administration

You can access docker containers under `/var/lib/docker/containers/<container id>/`, but where can you access it's contents under, they have to be stored on the server somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you create container you map volume with -v server:container_location or -v volume_name:container_location

you did not provide how you set your container. So, you can check with

```
docker inspect CONTAINER_NAME.
```

See maped folders or/and docker volumes

also, can execute command on macine where you run docker in the container.

```
docker exec CONTAINER_NAME command
```

(you can ls for example or bash in to the container)

all depends on how contaiter created.

you you provide docker Run.... string you use. you probobly will get more help.

For documentation check

> you need to specify volume driver options, you must use --mount.
> -v or --volume: Consists of three fields, separated by colon characters (:). The fields must be in the correct order, and the meaning of each field is not immediately obvious.
> In the case of named volumes, the first field is the name of the volume, and is unique on a given host machine. For anonymous volumes, the first field is omitted.
> The second field is the path where the file or directory are mounted in the container.
> The third field is optional, and is a comma-separated list of options, such as ro. These options are discussed below.
> --mount: Consists of multiple key-value pairs, separated by commas and each consisting of a = tuple. The --mount syntax is more verbose than -v or --volume, but the order of the keys is not significant, and the value of the flag is easier to understand.
> The type of the mount, which can be bind, volume, or tmpfs. This topic discusses volumes, so the type is always volume.
> The source of the mount. For named volumes, this is the name of the volume. For anonymous volumes, this field is omitted. May be specified as source or src.
> The destination takes as its value the path where the file or directory is mounted in the container. May be specified as destination, dst, or target.
> The readonly option, if present, causes the bind mount to be mounted into the container as read-only.
> The volume-opt option, which can be specified more than once, takes a key-value pair consisting of the option name and its value.

https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/